# Parameterized Flat File Connection String

Tags: csv, dynamic, ssis, connection-string

I'm using a Script Task(VB) to get the complete file path for a specific csv file that I want to load in SQL Server table. In the Script Task I loop through the directory (based on certain conditions) and assign the file path to a writable package variable as:

```
Dts.Variables("User::strPFilePath").Value = Folder + "\" + File.Name
```

Now I have the complete CSV file path and I set this up by parameterizing the csv connection manager with the property expression ConnectionString using this variable to dynamically assign the connection string.

This works fine when I run the package in Visual Studio but when I deploy it to SQL Server under SSISDB folder I get the following error specifically at that script task:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

The Data Flow Task after the script task generates the following error:

> Cannot open the datafile""

The second message to me implies that the file path is not being passed dynamically to the ConnectionManager for the CSV.

Any ideas on how I can fix this or deploy it properly?

Thanks

Comment: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" = You got a problem with your script task. Nothing more. You get that error every time. In order to find the actual error add a breakpoint.

Comment: Hi @KeithL But that's the thing. When I run the the Package in Visual Studio directly I don't get this error. The script completes and does what it is supposed to do...?

Comment: I don't know about VB but in C# you would get an error for using escape character. Try Path.Combine(folder,File.Name) instead.

Comment: does Agent have access to the folder?

Comment: +1 for the Agent account not having access to the folder. Probably why you are getting a blank value in the variable. When you run in VS, it runs under the context of *your* windows account. When you run via the Agent, it runs under the context of *the windows account running the Agent service*. And that user needs access. Remember it will also be running on the server, not your computer. If drives exist for your user on your computer, and not for the agent account on the server, you will have similar issues.

Comment: Hi @KeithL I think the agent is looking more like a line of enquiry which I need to follow up with IT

Comment: Hi @JacobH. Thanks. I will be making some enquiries into this.